# Bash says my directory does not exist while trying to $export

Tags: bash, vulkan

I am trying to install the Vulkan SDK on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have the AMD guide in front of me, and I'm still having the issue that Bash insists there is no file/directory when I input:

```
$export VULKAN_SDK=/my/path/to/vulkan/
```

Now I have switched to that directory to assure myself it exists, and I have

```
chmod +u+x
```

on it as well. I even tried the same command under

```
sudo su.
```

The last thing to check was that I had the proper architecture, and I am running a 64-bit system and I do in fact have the x86_64 bit binaries downloaded, only I am not even trying to use a file, only to set a path. What's the problem?

Comment: It would be create if you can paste the full terminal output from the error occurring including all commands run and all outputs, as well as the output of "ls -lad /my /my/path /my/path/to /my/path/to/vulkan"

Comment: What *exactly* are you typing? `$export` or `export`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to remove the '$' before export. Or did you accidentally copy the '$' from the terminal?

`$` in a command example means that the command is to be executed as user, `#` would mean that it is to be executed as root. For an example, open your terminal and look at the prompt:

`user@machine:~$`

versus what you see if you switch to root with `sudo su`:

`root@machine:~#`

Comment: no i just followed how the guide wrote it

Comment: you were absolutely right, though and I appreciate your help. I've never messed around with environmental variables before, had that one wrong for sure.